# LPTHW Exercise 52: Attribute Error

Tags: python, web.py, attributeerror

I try to solve exercise 52 of the book "Learn Python the hard way", but I get stuck at a certain error.

It is an exercise that uses the web.py module.

When I load the file with "python bin/app.py" and look up the page with my browser I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'room'
```

Can you help me find out why this error occurs?

It seems that this line

```
session.room = map.START
```

does not edit the session file properly. I decoded the session file and got the following:

```
>>> x = base64.b64decode(open("sessions/15efb89316fa05f7c77e614ab1ddb70e918b9af3").read())
>>> pickle.loads(x)
{'ip': u'127.0.0.1', 'room': None, 'session_id': '15efb89316fa05f7c77e614ab1ddb70e918b9af3'}
```

The file structure is as follows:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── app_old.py
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── app.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   └── session_sample.py
├── docs
├── gothonweb
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── map.py
├── map.pyc
├── sessions
│   └── 15efb89316fa05f7c77e614ab1ddb70e918b9af3
├── static
│   └── main.css
├── templates
│   ├── layout.html
│   ├── show_room.html
│   └── you_died.html
└── tests
    ├── app_tests.py
    ├── app_tests.pyc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── map_tests.py
    ├── map_tests.pyc
    ├── tools.py
    └── tools.pyc
```

app.py

```
import web
import map

urls = (
        '/game', 'GameEngine',
        '/', 'Index',
    )

app = web.application(urls, globals())

# little hack so that debug mode works with sessions
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    session = web.session.Session(app, store, initializer={'room': None})

else:
    session = web.config._session

render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        # this is used to "setup" the session with starting values
        session.room = map.START
        print "session room var:" + str(session.room)
        web.seeother("/game")

class GameEngine(object):

    def GET(self):
        if session.room:
            return render.show_room(room=session.room)
        else:
            #why is there here? do you need it?
            return render.you_died()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(action=None)

        # there is a bug here, can you fix it?
        if session.room and form.action:
            session.room = session.room.go(form.action)

        web.seeother("/game")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

map.py

```
class Scene(object):

    def enter(self):
        pass

class Desert(Scene):

    def enter(self, hero):
        print "You're in the desert after the plane crashed. Choose a path. You can go west to the plane, south to the village Waikiki and east to the dungeon."
        action = raw_input("[east, west, south]>")
        if action == "east":
            return Dungeon()
        elif action == "west":
            return Plane()
        elif action == "south":
            return Waikiki()
        elif action == "north":
            return Room("Goldroom", "Look out for monsters!")

class Plane(Scene):
    def enter(self, hero):
        print "This is the plane you used to come to this place. It is completely broken."
        actions = ['investigate', 'return']
        action = ""
        while action not in actions: 
            action = raw_input("[investigate, return] >")
        if (action == actions[0]):
            print "You investigate the plane and you find a health-care package"
            hero.obtain_item("health-care package")
            return self
        elif (action == actions[1]):
            return Desert()



class Dungeon(Scene):

    def enter(self, hero):
        print "You are in the dungeon. Lots of monsters are here. Take care!"

        for i in range(0,3):
            print "There is a huge bat!"
            battle = Battle("bat", i+1, hero)
            outcome = battle.fight()
        if outcome:
            return Dungeon_b()
        else:
            return Death()

class Dungeon_b(Scene):

    def enter(self, hero):
        print "this is great, you won the game"
        return Win()

class Waikiki(Scene):

    def enter(self, hero): 
        print hero.name + " goes to the village leader. He greats you and let you go. But than an arrow comes from far and kills you."
        return Death()

class Death(Scene):
    def enter(self, hero):
        print "You died. Try again."
        exit(1)

class Win(Scene):
    def enter(self, hero):
        print "You brought " + hero.name + " to the finish. Great!"
        exit(1)

class Room(object):

    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.paths = {}

    def go(self, direction):
        return self.paths.get(direction, None)

    def add_paths(self, paths):
        self.paths.update(paths)

central_corridor = Room("Central Corridor", "description about central corridor")
laser_weapon_armory = Room("Laser Weapon Armory", "description about laser weapon armory")
the_bridge = Room("The Bridge", "description of the bridge")
escape_pod = Room("Escape Pod", "description of the escape pod")
the_end_winner = Room("The End", "description of the end scene")
the_end_loser = Room("The End", "description of the end scene when the player died.")

escape_pod.add_paths({
    '2': the_end_winner,
    '*': the_end_loser
    })

generic_death = Room('death', 'You died')

the_bridge.add_paths({
    'throw the bomb': generic_death,
    'slowly place the bomb': escape_pod
    })

laser_weapon_armory.add_paths({
    '0132': the_bridge,
    '*': generic_death
    })

central_corridor.add_paths({
    'shoot!': generic_death,
    'dodge!': generic_death,
    'tell a joke': laser_weapon_armory })

START = central_corridor
```

Comment: You want `session['room']`, I think, not `session.room`.

Comment: the line print "session room var:" + str(session.room) prints session room var:<map.Room object at 0x7f12263faf10> so syntax is right